# What are the question tags for ‘may’, ‘must’ ‘let's’, and ‘let us’?

Tags: questions, modal-verbs

What are the question tags for sentences containing *may*, *must*, *let's*, and *let us*? Are the tags used in the following sentences correct?

***may***
1. I may buy a car tomorrow, mightn't I?
2. I may buy a car tomorrow, *won't* I?

***must***
3. You must be tired after that long walk, mustn’t you?
4. It must be very cold outside, isn't it?

***let's*** / ***let us***
5. Let's go to the movies tonight, shall we?
6. Let us go to the movies tonight, will you?

Comment: Related question, [“He must have overslept, mustn't he?” versus “… , hasn't he?” or “… , didn't he?” Which is correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286893/he-must-have-overslept-mustnt-he-versus-hasnt-he-or-didnt-he).

Comment: The main "question tag" is the question mark.  It implies that there is a rising tone at the end of the sentence, and that can turn a regular statement into a question.  Furthermore, a properly written sentence without the question mark implies that there is no question (and no rising tone), even when the words seem to imply otherwise.

Comment: And as to having words that are (rather curiously) referred to as a "question tag", there is no defined connection between the verb in a declarative sentence and the phrasing of any associated interrogatory sentence or clause.  You may use any words that seem to fit the situation.

Answer (score 1):

***I may buy a car tomorrow***.
This is a statement.  The person who says it has no reason to make a tag question at the end.  The person they are talking to would probably say  '***Really***?'  At a push they might say "***Might you*** ?"

***You must be tired after that long walk*** and ***It must be very cold outside.*** Both of these sound like a surmise (*an idea that something may be true, but without certainty; a conjecture* -OED). In both cases the most likely interrogative form to follow would not be a tag but a direct question -

*You must be tired after that long walk*.  "***Aren't you***?"

*It must be very cold outside.* "***Is it***?"

***Let's go to the movies tonight, shall we***? (not "*will you*?")

Comment: "You must be tired after that long walk?" is a perfectly good question without adding "Aren't you?"

Comment: @HotLicks - Your question mark at the end makes a question of the sentence.  Of course. Without the question mark - and the sentence would, arguably, more usually be written *without* a question mark - the comment is  conjectural and not necessarily inviting an answer.  It could be spoken in a questioning way.  Or not.  Besides the OP is interested in the appropriate tag question. As my answer tries to explain, this formulation is not usually given a question tag.  Instead, a direct question follows immediately after.

Comment: The appropriate "question tag" is "?".